# error ''there is already an object name in databases''

Tags: sql-server, ddl

Can you help me fix the error

> There is already an object name in database

My code:

```
CREATE DATABASE DIEMTHAMQUAN

USE DIEMTHAMQUAN


CREATE TABLE QUOCGIA
(
    MAQG NCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    TENQG NCHAR(20) NULL,
    TD NCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    DS INT NULL,
    DT REAL NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_QUOCGIA PRIMARY KEY(MAQG,TD)
)

CREATE TABLE TINHTHANH
(
    MATT NCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    QG NCHAR(5) NULL,
    DS INT NULL,
    DT REAL NULL,
    TENTT NCHAR(30) NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_TINHTHANH PRIMARY KEY(MATT)
)

CREATE TABLE DIEMTHAMQUAN
(
    MADTQ NCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    TENDTQ NCHAR(30) NULL,
    TT NCHAR(5) NULL,
    QG NCHAR(5) NULL,
    DD NCHAR(50) NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_DIEMTHAMQUAN PRIMARY KEY(MADTQ)
)

ALTER TABLE TINHTHANH 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TT_QG FOREIGN KEY(QG) REFERENCES QUOCGIA(MAQG)
ALTER TABLE DIEMTHAMQUAN 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DTQ_TT FOREIGN KEY(TT) REFERENCES TINHTHANH(MATT)

--insert QUOCGIA(MAQG,TENQG,TD,DS,DT) 
INSERT INTO QUOCGIA(MAQG, TENQG, TD, DS, DT) 
VALUES (N'QG001', N'VIỆT NAM', N'TT001', CAST(N'115000000' AS INT), CAST(N'331688.00' AS REAL)),
       (N'QG002', N'NHẬT BẢN', N'TT003', CAST(N'129500000' AS INT), CAST(N'337834.00' AS REAL))


--insert  TINHTHANH(QG,MATT,TENTT,DS,DT)
INSERT INTO TINHTHANH(QG, MATT, TENTT, DS, DT) 
VALUES (N'QG001', N'TT001', N'HÀ NỘI', CAST(N'2500000' AS INT), CAST(N'927.39' AS REAL)),
       (N'QG001', N'TT002', N'HUẾ', CAST(N'5344000' AS INT), CAST(N'5009.00' AS REAL)),
       (N'QG002', N'TT003', N'TOKYO', CAST(N'12084000' AS INT), CAST(N'2187.00' AS REAL))
```

Comment: Read the error again. It's telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Before create table, check if it exists.  Google for the syntax.

Comment: Try reading the error. It's already defined

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
CREATE TABLE DIEMTHAMQUAN
```

You are using the same name for the ‘Database’ and guving the same name to a ‘table’. If in future you call this ‘DIEMTHAMQUAN’ how would Sql-Server(if you are using this) know that you are referring to database or table.

Possible solution is to name your table ‘tblDIEMTHAMQUAN’.